# Is there hyperspectral drone imagery available for free for research

Tags: images

We are just looking at testing some processes before purchasing a hyperspectral drone sensor and was wondering if anyone knows any sites where we can download a few sq km of data for testing. It can be anywhere in the world and ideally at a river mouth with sedimentation.

I have checked some of the camera suppliers websites but can't find any sample data. They should all supply some on their websites for people to check what can be expected before purchasing. The white paper specs are just not enough sometimes.

Something similar to https://www.tomstechtime.com/downloads/ would be ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a few example I found.

NASA supplies some free AVIRIS hyperspectral data.
https://aviris.jpl.nasa.gov/data/free_data.html

Here’s an example of using the AVIRIS data. 
http://www.microimages.com/downloads/hyperspectral.htm

Resonon supplies some sample data with a free version of their hyperspectral analysis tool.
https://www.resonon.com/Products/spectronon.html

Professor D. H. Foster has posted various hyperspectral images to his webpage.
http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/d.h.foster/default.html